# TypeError: setOpenLoginDialog is not the Function

Tags: javascript

```
    export default function LoginForm({setOpenLoginDialog}) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const handleLoginClick = () => {  
    setOpenLoginDialog(false)  
  }

  console.log("login", email);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root} >
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div>
          <TextField
            id="email"
            name="email"
            label="Email ID"
            type="text"
            value={email.email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail({...email, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})} />
          {/* <p className="errMsg">{emailErr}</p> */}

          <TextField
            id="standard-password-input"
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            value={password.password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword({...password, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})}
          />
          {/* <p className="errMsg">{passwordErr}</p> */}

        </div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}
          onClick={handleLoginClick}>Login
          {/* <Link to="/logout">Login</Link> */}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

type error is coming in my code on setOpenLoginDialog()... error is setOpenLoginDialog is not a function. I use this function by using props... please give me the impressive answer .. it is a reactjs code.

Comment: Can you show the `<LoginForm ... />` part of the parent's JSX? Are you sure whatever you have in `setOpenLoginDialog={...}` exists? ("is not a function" most likely means "is undefined")

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import MoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';

import Signup from '../Components/Profile/Signup'
import SignUpForm from './SignUpForm';
import Logins from '../Components/Profile/Logins'
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'block',
    },
  },
  
  sectionDesktop: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
  },
  sectionMobile: {
    display: 'flex',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
}));

export default function Header() {

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = React.useState(false);
  const [openLoginDialog, setOpenLoginDialog] = React.useState(false);


  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    handleMobileMenuClose();
  };

  const handleMobileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const menuId = 'primary-search-account-menu';
  const renderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={menuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>
        <h6 onClick={()=> setOpenDialog(true)} style={{color: "gray"}}>Sign Up</h6>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>
        <h6 onClick={()=> setOpenLoginDialog(true)}
        style={{color: 'gray'}}>Login</h6>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    
  );

  const mobileMenuId = 'primary-search-account-menu-mobile';
  const renderMobileMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={mobileMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMobileMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="account of current user"
          aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <AccountCircle />
        </IconButton>
        <p>Profile</p>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            {/* <MenuIcon /> */}
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
            <Link to='/'><h3 style={{fontWeight: 'bold', 
            textDecoration: 'none', 
            color: 'whitesmoke',
            marginTop : 10}}>FIRST-APP</h3></Link>
          </Typography>
          
          <div className={classes.grow} />
          <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>
            
            <IconButton
              edge="end"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls={menuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.sectionMobile}>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="show more"
              aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMobileMenu}
      {renderMenu}
      <Signup
        openDialog={openDialog}
        setOpenDialog={setOpenDialog}
        >
          <SignUpForm 
          setOpenDialog={setOpenDialog}/>
      </Signup>

      <Logins 
      openLoginDialog={openLoginDialog}
      setOpenLoginDialog={setOpenLoginDialog}>
        <LoginForm/>
      </Logins>
    </div>
  );
}
```